# RFID-RD522 com Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

Bom dia galera!!

Estou tentando conectar um módulo **RFID** com **PYHTON** no **Raspberry B**

Eu segui os seguintes tutorias:

http://blog.filipeflop.com/embarcados/controle-de-acesso-rfid-com-raspberry-pi.html

http://www.embarcados.com.br/rfid-raspberry-pi-python/

Aparentemente está tudo ok, mas na hora em que coloco o sistema para rodar, simplesmente não funciona, fica esperando eu aproximar o cartão, eu aproximo e não dá em nada!

Alguém já passou por isso e pode me ajudar?

Desde já sou grato a todos...

> ***nunca programei em python, e nem tinha usado o linux (Raspbian)***

Comment: boa noite , cara consegui usando o seguinte link: configurar o rfid no raspberry(usando o raspbian)
http://www.embarcados.com.br/rfid-raspberry-pi-python/